# why must I use {} in JS require() statement

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm very new to Javascript and I am trying to connect to a mongodb database by following [this guide](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database).

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb')

/*
Username: myusername
Key: mykey
*/

connString = 'mongodb+srv://<myusername>:<mykey>@' +
             'cluster0.vpss6.mongodb.net/<dbname>?' + 
             'retryWrites=true&w=majority'

const client = new MongoClient(connString, {useUnifiedTopology: true})

databaseList = client.db().admin().listDatabases()

databaseList.then(function(result)  {

  console.log(result)

})
```

Whenever I omit the `{}` around the `{MongoClient}` line the code breaks I receive a `Uncaught TypeError: client.db is not a function` error message further down at the `databaseList = client.db().admin().listDatabases()` line. This also applies to when I switch the `const` declarations to `var` declarations.

Why is this?

Comment: The `{ }` in the declaration extract the property named "MongoClient" from the object exported by the library.

Comment: Nodejs uses "commonJS". Try it like this `const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient`